# How to call Phone number with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to call a phone number with Microsoft Graph API. I can call with bot some user with his ID, but now I need to call external phone number. Is it possible? I'm talking about PSTN numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign PSTN number to a [bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communications-phone-number). But bot cannot make a call to a PSTN number.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported yet, PSTN calling is disabled for Bots, you can look at the following [discussion](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues/29)

Comment: What about getPstnCalls? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-getpstncalls?view=graph-rest-beta . It returns all PSTN calls that i did?